# What is dunking?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

I thought dunking was a build that master yi does and yells GET DUNKED, but I keep hearing people talk about dunking, without the nooblord build.  What does this mean?

For reference this is the nooblord dunk build:

Comment: I don't understand what is so wrong with this question. It has over 7.5k views - those are hits from people as me who would like to know what the hell is dunking.

Answer (score 2):

I also recall it being mentioned in the context of "dunk strat",in this case it refers to a team composition revolving around having several champions capable of jumping and isolating an enemy champion from the rest of his team (hopefully) long enough to kill him, and dunking in this context refers to the execution of this strategy. An example of a dunk strat champion would be Jarvan IV with his ultimate, cataclysm.

Answer (score 0):

It has probably just become a meme from the nooblord Yi build. The video is popular enough that a number of players have seen it and quote it when they do something exceptional to another player.